# Can the opacity of a Google Maps GInfoWindow or GMarker be changed separately from the maps opacity?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I've built a Google Map window that uses two tile layers. The opacity of each layer can be adjusted dynamically using javascript. When I adjust the opacity of a tile layer, all child controls including GMarkers and GInfoWindows inherit the opacity setting. Is there any way to ensure that the Markers and InfoWindows are always visible regardless of the maps opacity? In other words, is there some trick to making sure they're always on top?  I've tried altering the opacity and z-Index of the html in the info window to no effect.

One workaround I've considered is duplicateing the GMarkers on each tile layer, then popping my own custom divs instead of GInfoWindows. If someone has gone that route, I'd appreciate seeing an example instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for .....

[Example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1/examples/infobox-basic.html)

From a library called [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1/docs/reference.html)

Using this opacity option:

```
var myOptions = {

                  opacity: 0.75

}
```